# encrypted final destination IP location is fixed in the VPN packet?

Tags: encryption, vpn, sniffing, cracking

I just wonder that someone sniff my VPN packet and find out where I visit. If destination IP location is fixed in the encrypted packet, I think it's not that hard to decrypt destination IP by copying the IP part and attempt to dictionary attack. Anyone knows about this?

Comment: What would a “dictionary attack” entail? (The exceedingly likely answer is that no, someone can’t just do that.)

Comment: Also, which VPN protocol?

Comment: dictionary attack means something like "asleap" - [I found how to decrypt VPN packet from this document](https://www.cloudcracker.com/blog/2012/07/29/cracking-ms-chap-v2/)

Comment: probably MS-CHAPv2? I have to do research VPN is really secure... if protocol make them different, I have to compare them ... sigh...